# I am having issue while installing Flutter in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, snap, android, paths

I used snap to install flutter, i.e. `sudo snap install flutter --classic`
After when I run `flutter sdk-path` it shows the following.

[image: output]

The same happened when I tried manually downloading the .zip, setting up the path, and running `flutter doctor`.